# Rendering Partial not being rendered .NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I'm running into an issue in rendering partials. I've looked around and found you're supposed to pass the path to the partial view as the first parameter, and your model to the second parameter if you're using one since it's one of the overloads. I'm getting the page, without anything blowing up, but the partial view is not outputting my expected results, and I cannot hit a breakpoint on that partial (It's using a loop). I've confirmed I'm passing it a model with data, but the partial doesn't seem to be getting hit. Here is my controller and partials.

```
    DataBass db = new DataBass();

    public ActionResult Address()
    {
        Models.ViewModels.CheckoutViewModel x = new Models.ViewModels.CheckoutViewModel();

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            using(DataBass oDB = new DataBass())
            {
                var Customer = oDB.Customers.First(c => c.Email.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());
                var AvailableAddresses = oDB.AddressBooks.Where(ab => ab.CustomerID == Customer.ID).ToList();
                x.CustomerID = Customer.ID;
                x.HasExistingAddresses = (AvailableAddresses.Count > 0 ? false : true);
                x.AvailableAddresses = AvailableAddresses;


            }
            //var UserAddresses = db.AddressBooks.Where(a => a.Customer.Email == User.Identity.Name);
            //ViewBag.Addresses = UserAddresses;
            return View("Shipping", x);
        }                
        else
            return View("Index");
    }
```

And here is the partial view that I'm having troubles with. This is what's not getting hit.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.AddressBook>

<h2>AddressBook</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Address 2
        </th>
        <th>
           Address 1
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            State
        </th>
        <th>
            Postal Code
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var states = (List<Models.State>)ViewBag.States;

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @states.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == item.StateID).Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zipcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Choose this one","", new { id = item.ID}, new { @class="button"})
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAddress", new { id = item.ID }, null) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAddress", new { id = item.ID }, null)

                @*<a href="/Account/EditAddress/@item.AddressBook_ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a href="/Account/DeleteAddress/@item.AddressBook_ID">Delete</a>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAddress", new { id = item.ID }, null) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAddress", "Account",new { id=item.AddressBook_ID }, htmlAttributes: null ) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAddress", new { id = item.ID }, null)*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

And here is my view that's calling the renderpartial method to the ChooseExistingAddress.cshtml partial shown above.

```
@model Models.ViewModels.CheckoutViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shipping Selection";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Shipping</h2>
@if (Model.HasExistingAddresses)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Checkout/ChooseExistingAddress.cshtml", Model.AvailableAddresses);

}
else
{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Checkout/AddNewShippingAddress.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: Change "~/Views/Checkout/ChooseExistingAddress.cshtml" to "ChooseExistingAddress", "Checkout"

Comment: Modified it to Html.RenderPartial("ChooseExistingAddress", Model.AvailableAddresses); and I still get the same result. There isn't an overload for view, controller and model.

Comment: Looking at your partial, it looks like you have some invalid razor comments, you have an opening comment next to the first edit link but no matching closing tag

Comment: I removed the comments from the partial and still have no breakpoint being hit, and nothing renders to it's place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your ternary logic backwards:

```
x.HasExistingAddresses = (AvailableAddresses.Count > 0 ? false : true);
```

In other words, if count of addresses is greater than 0, you're setting it to false, whereas, it should be true, in that case. You don't really need a ternary, here, anyways. Just set it to the result of the boolean expression:

```
x.HasExistingAddresses = AvailableAddresses.Count > 0;
```

Comment: You could simplify it even further by using LINQ's Any method; AvailableAddresses.Any(). Using the Count property will be faster, but i doubt there will be a noticeable difference

Comment: This worked. Thanks, was a novice mistake on my part.